# magento2: add static block to header menu

Tags: magento2, static-block, header, create

My Categories are displayed in my Header **Main menu**. Now I want to add **another link( called 'about us')** after the last category in my header. 
I plan to **create a static cms block** -> in it's content put some html:

```
<ul>
    <li class="ui-menu-item level0">
        <a href="#" class="level-top"><span>About Us</span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

then add this static block to the header. **How can I achieve this ?**

Comment: you need to override the **topmenu.phtml ** are you using any custom theme ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly you need to create static cms block about us. and add your content in content part.

Now to add that block in header follow the **below steps** :

1. Create/Add new category from product/categories from admin menu.
2. Make Sure Enable Categories menu and Include in menu is selected as
   enable.
3. Click on Content tab and go to the **Add CMS Block** - Select your **about
   us cms block** from there.
4. From D**isplay settings** , Select **Display mode** as a **Statick Block only**
   and **Anchor** as **yes**.
5. Click on Save button and after that run the **cache:clean** command and check.

Screenshot for select **static block** :
[image]

Screenshot of **display settings :**

[image]

**Note :** You can also do it same thing by overriding the respected **template**.

Answer (score 1):

Create static block from **CONTENT->BLOCKS**

If you need About-Us as category link then you do not need to add from template. It would be better if you add it as category.

Go to **Products->Categories**

Create **About-Us** category

Go to the content tab from **Add CMS Block** select your block.

[image]

Go to the **Display Setting** from  **Display Mode** select **Static Block** only

[image]

Answer (score 0):

and what about is we have too many pages under about us. how can we tackle overflow in menu? how can we make menu Scrollable?