# Magento 2 call static block in the top menu navigation

Tags: magento2

How to add the static block in top menu navigation in the home page in magento 2?

Ie) in the below menu, i need to add a static block(image) to the top or right

[image]

**Something like this:**

[image]

I have just created the static Block from admin from Content->Blocks, 
I need to know like how to use the static block in the top menu.

Please give an example.

Comment: Is it that what are You looking for ? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147417/magento2-add-static-block-to-header-menu/147438

Comment: I don't want a link , I want to add a static block which has an image on the top menu , whixh should appear on mouse hover, as shown in my image